# How to extract audio from mov, or directly convert mov 2 ogg, on OSX?

Tags: audio, quicktime, ogg

I have a number of sound-only `.mov` files that I need in an audio format, preferably `.wav` or `.ogg`. What are the options to achieve this conversion on a Mac?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

QuickTime Pro can export the audio from a .mov file. I know it can export as .wav, maybe .mp3 as well.

You can also use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) to export the audio from a .mov file on OS X. [These directions reference the Windows version](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1266-extracting-the-sound-from-a-video-with-vlc) of VLC but should get you pretty close to how to do it on OS X.

Comment: Thanks - VLC did the trick for me, though not via the instructions you linked above. I followed those given by Anonymous Freak at http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-180744.html (originally for the opposite conversion).

Answer (score 2):

Opening the MOV directly with Audacity worked fine for me. Also, I wanted to have that audio on Audacity for some processing, so it was just about ideal.

Comment: What was the version of Audacity you used?

Comment: @wonea audacity 2.0.6 http://sourceforge.net/projects/audacity/files/audacity-win-2.0.6.exe **with ffmpeg for audacity** installed check this out http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/faq_installation_and_plug_ins.html#How_do_I_download_and_install_the_FFmpeg_Import.2FExport_Library.3F

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Fission](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/fission/) by Rogue Amoeba, a lossless editor as well as converter. It's shareware.

I just tested it on a MOV file, and it saved the audio as ogg with no problem. (I checked the ogg audio with VLC, and could hear no difference from the original MOV.)

I also checked two of the free alternatives (XLD and Max), but they choked on the input format. There are probably others, and one may work. But Fission definitely works.

[Followup - [IanC](https://superuser.com/users/26633/ian-c) has it. VLC will export to ogg.]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and for testing it. However, given that I had VLC installed already, so I tried it first. Since that worked fine, Fission's note on the download page stating "Before purchase, audio saved with Fission will be degraded with a series of audio fades." did not seem particularly inviting, so I did not try it.

Answer (score 0):

[MediaCoder](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/)  Media transcoder, it can extract audio from a video file, and can make a number of conversions, it will also run on a mac (sort of, but has decent support to make it work).

Comment: Thanks - this seems to be an interesting option for the long run. Will keep it in mind for upcoming file conversions, but did not try it this time.

Answer (score 0):

GarageBand also works for pulling the audio out of a `.mov` file. You have to create a movie project, which then displays the audio beneath the video track. In the `Track` menu, you select the option to `Hide Video Track`. I think the keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>. This removes the video and changes the project into a regular audio project, and you can export the song to iTunes, etc. I'm using GarageBand '11 (6.0.5), so depending on your version, the option might not be there. I don't know which version was the first one to include support for video projects.

Answer (score 0):

How to convert a .mov file to an audio file:

- open the file in QuickTime Player
- go to File > Export…
- for Format, select "Audio Only"

Then you can convert it to MP3 in iTunes